# How to get average from counting values?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, percentage

I am using SQLite.

I need to determine average impressions per day, where impression = count of person_id.

COLUMNS:

- person_id - unique identifier of the person
- date - date they were shown the ad
- ad_id - content of the ad: ad_1_product1, ad_2_product2, or ad_3_product3
- clicked (TRUE/FALSE) - clicked on the ad
- signed_up - (TRUE/FALSE) created an account
- subscribed (TRUE/FALSE) - started a paid    subscription

I set clicked, signed_up and subscribed as BOOLEAN, the rest is text.

MY CODE:

SELECT AVG(impressions) AS avg_impressions
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(person_id) as impressions
FROM videoadcampaign
GROUP BY date
) date;

I get 1 row with 1 colum avg_impression = 591

I cannot break down the average by date. Date is in 2021-04-27 format, total date count is 8.

result

[image: result]

expected, ignore the column name, it's just to show you

[image: expected, ignore the column name, it's just to show you]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add sample data along with the expected output.

Comment: The subquery returns the number of rows for each day. First execute this subquery and inspect the results.  Is it ok? If yes then the average of theses results should also be ok. Or is it something else that you want.

Comment: added some pics to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the percentage of rows for each day, then you can do it by dividing each day's count by the total number of rows.

With `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT date, 1.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS avg_impressions
FROM videoadcampaign 
GROUP BY date
```

Or, with a subquery:

```
SELECT date, 1.0 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videoadcampaign) AS avg_impressions
FROM videoadcampaign 
GROUP BY date
```

I assume that the column `person_id` is not nullable, so instead of `COUNT(person_id)` you may use `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

The average impressions per day is the total impressions divided by the number of people.  No subquery is needed:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) AS avg_impressions
FROM videoadcampaign;
```

Comment: What is `impressions` in your code? There is no such column in the table.